# Get number of row using grouped columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have folowing sql query

```
select sta_name Station,count(factory_name) as factories from gps1
group by sta_name
order by sta_name
```

Through this query i am getting only total factories in a single Station.Problem is that i want to get the the result in the shape that factory number should also dispalye out of total factories in Station For Exampel If a Station has 5 factoreies then Five Factories should have this output

```
1/5
2/5
3/5
4/5
5/5
```

Any one please help me to get this type of result
**UPdate**
I Want this output
for example i have 5 factories in a station station1

```
factoryName      Count
factroty 1        1/5
factroty 2        2/5
factroty 3        3/5
factroty 4        4/5
factroty 5        5/5
```

Comment: No 1 is the number of factory out of total factories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn the count into an analytic function and remove the grouping:

```
select sta_name Station,count(factory_name) over(partition by sta_name) as factories from gps1
order by sta_name
```

Of course, if you want it like `1/5` then change it to:

```
select sta_name||'/'||count(factory_name) over(partition by sta_name) as factories from gps1
order by sta_name
```

**EDIT**: To mark it as, say, '1 out of 5', '2 out of 5', etc. then you can add a `row_number`:

```
select   FACTORY_NAME
        ,   row_number() over (partition by STA_NAME order by STA_NAME)
         || '/'
         || count(STA_NAME) over (partition by STA_NAME)
           as FACTORIES
from     GPS1
order by FACTORY_NAME
```

Comment: This Not My Desired Output it giving only total factories in a single station as it was in my above query please tell me for my desired out put

Comment: I've updated the code to include `partition`. In here you choose what column(s) you wish to group by. If that's not what you want then can you update your question with sample data and the expected result for that data.

Comment: Edited to add a row number as part of the query.

Comment: Yes Brother is Works Actualy I was only not adding this thing partition by STA_NAME.But it works now fine thanks a lot